# Buscar si existe un valor dentro de varios arreglos php

Tags: php, laravel, array, php7, symfony

Estoy trabajando en una parte donde necesito buscar dentro de varios arreglos si existe un valor que siempre dara la ocasion que esta en distintos arreglos, o mas bien el arreglo que lo contiene estara en distintas posiciones, en algunos casos puede ser el primer arreglo o bien el ultimo.

En este caso me figura en la posicion numero 7 de varios arreglos, por tanto lo busque de la siguiente forma

```
$product.features[7].id_feature==34
```

estp es que esta dentro de $product.features

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Modelo
            [value] => 55-VWF
            [id_feature] => 21
            [position] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Capacidad (Ah)
            [value] => 55
            [id_feature] => 11
            [position] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Arranque en frío (CCA)
            [value] => 480
            [id_feature] => 12
            [position] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Capacidad de Reserva (min)
            [value] => 75
            [id_feature] => 13
            [position] => 7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Voltaje
            [value] => 12 v
            [id_feature] => 14
            [position] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Posicion del borne
            [value] => 0 (Positivo derecho)
            [id_feature] => 15
            [position] => 11
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Terminal
            [value] => 01 (Standard)
            [id_feature] => 16
            [position] => 12
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Promocion
            [value] => 4x3
            [id_feature] => 34
            [position] => 33
        )

)
```

Mi pregunta es como buscar dentro de estos arreglos que exista el name 'Promocion' y si existe obtener la posicion del arreglo, puede ser [7] o puede ser [3] u otra, aqui mi problema con el codigo, muchas gracias

Comment: pues recorriendolos no!!!, for o foreach te serviran

Comment: ¿Cuando escribes $product.features[7].id_feature en realidad es $product['features'][7]['id_feature']?? puedes mostrar el código que imprime ese arreglo?

Comment: Estoy trabajando en prestashop la verdad y los archivos .tpl funcionan un poco distinto al backend que son extensiones .php  @Tabitha